# C++ IntelliCode not working properly in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellicode

I use Visual Studio 2019 Community and I just started to learn C++, but the IntelliCode looks not good. The "Desktop development with C++" installed along with its IntelliCode in the installer.

When I hover the mouse over a built-in function or class, it don't show me any description about it but at least I can see the syntax. I also can see the list of methods/properties when I start type. When I type a bracket or parenthesis the VS is not complete it automatically by its pair.

I use to code with C# and that's working fine! It shows the descriptions and complete automatically the brackets and so on... What is the problem with the C++, may I missed a setting?

Comment: Can you create a feedback ticket with some screenshots from Visual Studio? That will enable us to fix the issue for you efficiently and you will be update when the issue is fixed.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply! I already figured out that there's some option in the VS settings where I can enable the bracket thing. The other "issue" probably normal with C++.  That was weird for me because C# has much better support by the Intellisense, and almost every function has description and so on...  Instead C++ has much less description for functions (I saw a few times) and its intellicode also slower (error appear/disappear slower). Anyway, thanks but look this is the "normal" with C++. Probably, I will delete this question after you read my comment!

Comment: Thanks for you reply, if you think something can be better it is still worth leaving some feedback in the feedback system. Direct customer feedback often leads to good improvements.

Comment: I never used feedback system and don't really know how to do.. Also what is the point of it in my case? This "question" of mine isn't really a question for other people who using C++ according to the viewer count. The title of the question is also misleading after I realized that it is not a real error with VS (but they should improve the IntelliCode to how C# intellisense working, but we can't do anything for this here)